# How to export a regex from a module

Tags: regex, perl

I have a regex which I wish to export from my module, the code is as follows :

```
package regExport;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Exporter qw(import);
our @EXPORT_OK = qw(re);

my re = /.../; # my regex is here
```

and its being imported here

```
use regExport qw(re);
my @li = ("man", "qwrt", "mnbv", "azx", "aeiou");

foreach my $st (@li) {
     $li =~ a/b/; # I wish to test my regex on each of these strings
}
```

Anyone has any ideas how I would go about doing that. I'm feeling fairly confused on how to go about doing that.

Comment: If you would like to make portable exportable regex's, take a look at the Regexp::Common module.  https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Common  That way you don't have to mess with `Exporter`.  It also gives you gobs of pre-made regex.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest take, but which is not the best (see below), would be to make a variable with a pattern. Best use [qr operator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) for that, and then can export the variable

```
package RegExport;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Exporter qw(import);
our @EXPORT_OK = qw($re_pattern);

our $re_pattern = qr/(\w+)/i;  # capture a "word" case-insensitive

1;
```

Note that I've capitalized the package name, per the usual Perl convention of Pascal case.  (Then the file name need follow that and be `RegExport.pm`.)

This is then used as

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use FindBin qw($RealBin);
use lib $RealBin;

use RegExport qw($re_pattern);

my $text = q(Some text with a bunch of words. In sentences.);

while ($text =~ /$re_pattern/g) { 
    say "Word: $1";
}
```

Here I expect `RegExport.pm` to be in the same directory as the program. The use of [$RealBin](https://perldoc.perl.org/FindBin#EXPORTABLE-VARIABLES) is a good way to add to the search path for included libraries a directory relative to where the program itself is (in this case, the program's very directory).

If you really want to go with a variable like this (but read on!) then there is no need to export it from its package, but can use its fully qualified name in the caller

```
use RegExport;

... $RegExport::re_pattern ...
```

This is what is sometimes done in libraries for various settings.

However, the documentation has a bit to say about this, in a section  [What not to export](https://perldoc.perl.org/Exporter#What-Not-to-Export)

> Do **not** export variable names.
>
> ```
> @EXPORT_OK = qw($svar @avar %hvar); # DON'T!
> ```
>
> Exporting variables is not a good idea. They can change under the hood, provoking horrible effects at-a-distance that are too hard to track and to fix. Trust me: they are not worth it.

This good advice *is* occasionally violated in libraries, to a good effect; an example is `$RealBin` used above. But if you have no overriding reasons for that then better follow it -- and use a function to return the value

```
package RegExport;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Exporter qw(import);
our @EXPORT_OK = qw(get_pattern);

sub get_pattern {
    my @specs = @_;  # any input on how to form the pattern

    my $re_pattern = qr{...};

    return $re_pattern;
}

1;
```

and now you use it as

```
use RegExport qw(get_pattern);

my $re = get_pattern();   # or pass extra rules for how to form it
```

and use `$re` in a regex as a ready pattern.

Now both the users of this code and the future code maintainers are happy.

Comment: @Jan : any idea what is Perl equivalent of `/regex/.test(string)`

Comment: @MSS2001 That code tests in JS whether the regex matches the `string`, as a boolean? In perl you'd do `my $bool = $string =~ /regex/;` So `$bool` is either a truthy something (usually `1`) or falsey (usually empty string).  Often you'd just do `if ($string =~ /regex/) ...`.  This is what my example program uses in that `while` (I edited to add a full example.) If you assign in a "list context" (`my @matches = $string =~ /regex/;`) then you get back matches, not only true/false.

Comment: also that was extremely helpful bool and matches one :) thank you (very new to perl)

Comment: Exported variables can be made read-only to mitigate the issue.  The problem is in how the `Exporter` module does the import.  There are better ways to do it.

Answer (score 3):

You were close. There were just a few problems with your code:

- Variables you want to export to another package (i.e. `main`) need to be declared as package variables (with `our`) rather than lexical variables (with `my`).
- You're calling the match operator (`/ ... /`) rather than declaring and creating a regex. You need `qr/ ... /` instead.
- Although you loaded `Exporter`, you also need to make your class a subclass in order to use `import()`.
- Your package needs to return a true value at the end.

So I have this in the module:

```
package RegExport;

use strict;
use warnings;

use Exporter;

our @ISA = qw(Exporter);
our @EXPORT = qw($re);

our $re = qr/[aeiou]/; # my regex is here
    
1;
```

And this in the test program:

```
use lib '.';
use feature 'say';

use RegExport;

my @li = ("man", "qwrt", "mnbv", "azx", "aeiou");
    
foreach my $st (@li) {
  if ($st =~ /$re/) {
    say "Match: $st";
  } else {
    say "No match: $st";
  }
}
```

Note that I've changed the name of your package to `RegExport`. It's a tradition in Perl that standard user-defined modules start with a capital letter.